# tail probability for norm of normal random vector

Tags: probability-theory, distribution-tails

If $x \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I)$ is an $n$ dimensional random vector. I am looking for a proof of
$$ \mathrm{Prob}\left( \lVert x\rVert^2  \ge 6n \right) \le e^{-1.5n}$$

$\lVert x \rVert^2 \sim \chi^{2}$ with $n$ degrees of freedom. So we need a tail bound on a Chi squared random variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Chebyshev's inequality
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\|X\|^2 \geq k) \leq e^{-tk}\mathbb{E}[e^{t\|X\|^2}]
\end{align}
Since $\|X\|^2$ is chi-squared distributed with $n$ degrees of freedom,
$$ \mathbb{E}[e^{t\|X\|^2}] = (1-2t)^{-\frac{n}{2}}, \quad \forall t < \frac{1}{2}$$
Substituting $k = 6n $ in the first inequality,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\|X\|^2 \geq 6n) &\leq e^{-6tn}(1-2t)^{-\frac{n}{2}}\\
&= \exp\left[-n\left(6t+ \frac{1}{2}\log(1-2t)\right)\right]\\
&\leq \exp\left[- \frac{5 - \log 6}{2} n \right]  \textrm{ setting } t = \frac{5}{12}\\
&\leq e^{- 1.5n}\\
\end{align}

Comment: The chi-squared quantity is $\|X\|^2$, not $\|X\|$.

Comment: @kimchilover Fixed. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: That is Markov's ineq, though chebyshev's ineq itself can be derived from Markov inequality. Great anwer. Thanks.

Comment: @SPV Not sure what is the universally accepted nomenclature. Wikipedia says this is the "exponential Chebyshev's inequality". I prefer to use the more general $\mathbb{P}(|X| \geq \lambda) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[f(|X|)] }{f(\lambda)} $ for positive non-decreasing $f$ and $\lambda>0$, but don't know if there is a name for it.

Comment: That's Chernoff's bound https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound.